# wx-config not effect in codeblocks on linux

Tags: linux, codeblocks, wxwidgets, opensuse

I have build wxWidgets3.0.5 from source on Linux(OpenSuse15.4), and it is installed in /opt/wxWidgets.
wxWidgets' [hello world](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) example is build successful by the following command

```bash
g++ hello.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o hello
```

The program works OK. Which means my installation and enviroment variable is correct.

Then I am changing to codeblock to start a demo project following the [codeblocks wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide).And my setting in codeblocks is
[cb setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjD2w.png)

However, while I am build the project, error comes, with build log as following:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in demo (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -g -I../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0 -c /home/schoenberg/work/wxWidgets/demo/demoApp.cpp -o obj/Debug/demoApp.o
In file included from ../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0/wx/defs.h:27:0,
                 from ../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0/wx/event.h:14,
                 from ../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0/wx/app.h:19,
                 from /home/schoenberg/work/wxWidgets/demo/demoApp.h:13,
                 from /home/schoenberg/work/wxWidgets/demo/demoApp.cpp:10:
../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0/wx/platform.h:183:10: fatal error: wx/setup.h: 没有那个文件或目录
 #include "wx/setup.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

It is seems that the command is not correct, is should be

```bash
g++ -Wall `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -g -I../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0 -c sth_else
```

Does any one knows why wx-config is not effect in CB's setting?

thx.

I should see the build log like this

```bash
g++ -Wall `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -g -I../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0 -c sth_else
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use wx-config with codeblocks is to add `wx-config --cflags` to "Other compiler options" for the project root (not one of the targets) and `wx-config --libs` to "Other linker options".

The "Build options" dialogs should look like this:

[image]

[image]

You won't see `wx-config --cflags` or `wx-config --libs` in the build log - instead they'll be replaced with what those commands evaluate to.  On my system `wx-config --cflags` evaluates to

```
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

and `wx-config --libs` evaluates to

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

but other systems will be different. This results in codeblocks using compile commands like:

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Wall -g  -c /home/xyz/wxtest/wxtestMain.cpp -o obj/Debug/wxtestMain.o
```

and linker commands like:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/wxtest obj/Debug/GUIFrame.o obj/Debug/wxtestApp.o obj/Debug/wxtestMain.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

Comment: thx, I changed the CB's setting similar with you, but I cannot see the Other compiler's option setting clearly. Could you paste it here?
Then I tried again, the command is expanded by wx-config:
```
g++ -Wall -L/opt/wxWidgets/lib -pthread -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0 -g -I../../../../../opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0 -c ...
```
However it fails to find wx/setup.h. I searched my directory, there is no setup.h file.

Comment: And I rebuild the wxWidgets using following command: `./configure --prefix=/opt/wxWidgets --with-gtk3.0` then `make & make install`. There is no setup.h under /opt/wxWidgets/include/wx-3.0/wx/gtk either. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

finnally, I found what is wrong.
the complier setting should be set as

```
wx-config --cxxflag 64
```

that because the setup.h file is located in /opt/wxWidgets/lib64/wx
The wx-config will expand the g++ option -I to point to the correct setup.h location.
Of cause, LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be set correctly.